# Format Specifier for time_t?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, mfc

Do we have a format specifier for time_t ?

There are some useful format specifier for watching variable in watch window while debugging.

See MSDN [enter link description here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/75w45ekt.aspx)

I am missing a specifier for time_t (CTime) to see the value in a human readable format (ex 11:03:15) instead (1479204156).

Can we build our own specifier?

Comment: Have you resolved this?

Comment: Still not yet. But I think @anton shmelev points to the right direction

Answer (score 1):

It is not clear which version of VS you are using, but maybe this will help:
[Create custom views of native object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj620914.aspx).

Comment: That points to the right way.  Hm.. that looks not easy to do.